# How to use initiate GC on android java source?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

[image]

first, I don't know about GC, GC is if my app memory is insufficient, gc work unused memory release.

by the way, when I clicked `Initiate GC` button on android studio.
my app free memory increased.

before `Initiate GC` button click, my app free memory 2MB~ 3MB.
but when I click button, free memory 12MB.

As free memory grows, is it safe from memory leaks?

and I want when app start, execute `Initiate GC` button

I think use `System.gc()` but this command not increase Free memory.

how to use `Initiate GC` on java source?

thanks.

Comment: You don't have to.  The system calls GC as needed.  It would be an extremely rare app to need to call it manually.  More likely you just need to be more efficient with resources.  Also, note that the amount of free memory there is the free size of the already allocated heap, not the total free memory of the phone.  The heap can allocate more memory and grow.  Your size on that image is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

`System.gc()` is the only command to do it manually from Java. Otherwise it is done automatically by the virtual machine.

To prevent memory leaks, use local variables as far as possible and be sure to nullify the global references with no use so that the unreferenced objects will be cleared by the garbage collector.